# Identifying pairs of rows in dataframe where dates are within specified number of days

Tags: r

I'm attempting to create a dataset similar to how CMS publishes [referral data](https://questions.cms.gov/faq.php?faqId=7977). In short, two physicians are linked if they see the same patient within 30 days of another.

I have a dataset which contains patients, physicians, and appointment dates, e.g.:

```
df <- data.frame(
  doctor = c("Dr. Who", "Dr. Pepper", "Dr.Bob", "Dr. Strangelove"),
  patient = c("Mickey", "Mickey", "Mickey", "Mickey"),
  date = c("2015-01-15", "2015-01-21", "2015-04-01", "2015-02-18")
)
```

With the above dataset, I would like to write some R code that would return:

- Dr. Who, Dr. Pepper (because they see Mickey within 6 days of one another)
- Dr. Pepper, Dr. Strangelove (they see Mickey within 28 days of one another)

My actual dataset contains many more doctors, patients, and dates. I don't have much of a computer science background, but this seems like it would be a computationally taxing task.

In plain English, the way I would process this problem is:

1. Collect all patient appointments
2. For each appointment date, find the difference in days from all other appointment days
3. Return the doctor pairs for any two appointments that are +/- 30 days from one another.

Please let me know if I can improve my question in any way. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it with `mapply`, which applies a multivariate function elementwise. Here, it loops across the `doctor` and `date` columns, subsetting `df` to the doctors associated with dates within 30 days who are not the same doctor as that appointment. Multiple matches are combined with `paste( ... , collapse = ', ')`.

```
df$linked_doc <- mapply(
  function(doc, date){paste(
    df[abs(date - df$date) < 30 & doc != df$doctor, 'doctor'], 
    collapse = ', ')}, 
  df$doctor, df$date)

df
#            doctor patient       date               linked_doc
# 1         Dr. Who  Mickey 2015-01-15               Dr. Pepper
# 2      Dr. Pepper  Mickey 2015-01-21 Dr. Who, Dr. Strangelove
# 3          Dr.Bob  Mickey 2015-04-01                         
# 4 Dr. Strangelove  Mickey 2015-02-18               Dr. Pepper
```

There are other ways to do this, of course. If you have multiple patients, you can `split` on `patient` before applying the function.

Comment: Thank you!  I think I need to go back to old code and see where else I can utilize mapply.  I'm curious - is there another line of code you used to change df$date into the proper class that would work with the solution you gave? I had to do something like:                        `df$date<-parse_date_time(df$date, "%y%m%d")

df$linked_doc <- mapply(
  function(doc, date){paste(
    df[abs(date - df$date) < 2592000 & doc != df$doctor, 'doctor'], 
    collapse = ', ')}, 
  df$doctor, df$date)`       where 2592000 is 30 days in seconds. When I tried to use difftime(..), I received var type errors

Comment: Sorry, I should have included that! You need a date format, not a datetime one. In this case, all you need is `df$date <- as.Date(df$date)`. As your dates are already in ISO format, you don't even need to pass it a parsing string!

Comment: Related question  -  how would you go about splitting on patient first? Is it a matter of nesting an mapply inside an sapply?

Comment: There are options, but the simplest way might just be to add it as another variable and another condition: `mapply(
    function(doc, date, patient){paste(
        df[abs(date - df$date) < 30 & doc != df$doctor & patient == df$patient, 'doctor'], 
        collapse = ', ')}, 
    df$doctor, df$date, df$patient)`